# Can I set a different data directory for Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, command-line, google-chrome, sandbox

In Google Chrome, I can provide the command-line argument --user-data-dir="..." to have Chrome use a different directory for state like cookies, cache, and so forth.  This makes it possible to trivially load web pages from a "fresh" browser and simulate multiple independent users.

How can I do the same thing with Internet Explorer (either 6, 7, or 8)?

**Edit**:  It's looking like IE always uses the current user's profile, so you have to set up multiple users on the system and switch between them.  What a pain.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion I can think of would be to create multiple user accounts on the box, and then create shortcuts to Internet Explorer with the [RunAs command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781769.aspx) or use the Run As... [context menu option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781763.aspx).

See also:
http://www.krunk4ever.com/blog/2006/12/01/how-to-run-explorerexe-as-another-user/

Answer (score 0):

Heh.

With Chrome, FF, etc. I can actually have multiple *versions* on a single machine and test them without interference. IE requires me to set up VMs. Hence, the bulk of the code i churn out only gets tested rigorously on IE6 (since that's the install on the host OS). IE, if you'll pardon my slang, is a bitch - i've no idea how they manage to test it effectively within MS.

That said... You can *sort of* get what you want. If you're running XP and *aren't* on a domain, or are running Vista, you can configure "[Fast User Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_User_Switching)". Then, configure multiple user accounts. Finally, log into each one, launch IE in each one, and rest assured they're using different profiles / data directories. Alternately, if you're running one of the Server versions of Windows (i'm partial to 2k3 r2), you can set up Terminal Services and simply use [RDC](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/tools/rdclientdl.mspx) to create multiple concurrent logins.